# Screen Compatibility issues in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new in android and i am developing application . I have read in the developers.google.com that if i want the application screen compatible then my icons should be in ldpi , mdpi , hdpi , xhdpi and android itself will pick is it like this ? if not then what i have to do making it screen compatible and also how to give the dynamic padding ?  like right now my code is look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_page"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_login_btn"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_btn_register" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So , you see here i have give the margin top , but that work only on tablets not on large screen mobiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
see if u want to go with layout format that you have to make some drawable like 
1.drawable-hdpi
2.drawable-large
3.drawable-ldpi
4.drawable-xhdpi
5.drawable-xlarge-mdpi
6.drawable-xxhdpi

and make all layout respectively then your app is going fine on any mobile tablet blue stack AOC android device 

if u go with java code then 
    int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

    if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is high");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is xxhigh");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is xxxhigh");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV)
                            System.out.println("Density is Tv"); 

if(widthDp==600)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if (widthDp==720)
                    {

                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }

do what ever way u like :)
BEST OF LUCK DUDE :)
```

Comment: what if i put the different size images in mdpi , ldpi then also i have to do this ?

Comment: yes dear put all images in drawable folder and make all layout according to screen size :) you have to do it for all screen support

Comment: in res folder i have to create the firstly for layout-hdpi folder then layout-mdpi folder and like that ?

Comment: whats about the values folder how i have to create them ?

Answer (score 0):

For screen compatibility we can create folders like layout-large, layout-small under  res folder and paste all the layouts in each folder and adjust according to the screen size.
About icons we need to make different size icons and put it in respective folder .

Comment: ok so it have ldpi , mdpi , hdpi . xhdpi , xxhdpi so i have to create folder for all ? the name of all layout must be same ? how it will detect ? how can i know which one is for which device like which one is tablet and which one is s4 ? only doing different size of images and icon didnt work ?

Comment: No. when we create android projects in eclipse it will automatically create drawable-hdpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi folders under res folder. and one layout folder is also there, by default all the layout will be there.
if you want screen compatibility then create layout-large ,small like folders under res folder then copy all layouts from default folder and copy it to large-layout folder then adjust textsize,position etc according to the screen size.

Comment: but i want to know that nexus7 , galaxy nexus and 10.1in WXGA  are all in xhdpi ? or in different ?

Comment: nexu7 in tvdpi, galaxy nexus in xhdpi, 10.1 WXGA in mdpi..

You can check this in eclipse itself .. go to Window->Android Virtual device manager in that take device definitions..

Comment: whats about the values folder how i have to create that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **dimen.xml** files. There you can define values for different screen sizes

**/res/values/dimen.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_top">600dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**/res/values-large/dimen.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_top">800dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and in your layout use

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
```

Comment: so i have to create folder for each  ? hdpi ? mdpi ? ldpi ? and how it will detect ?

Comment: No. Resources from hdpi, mdpi, ldpi folders are picked by the screen density. For screen sizes you have `small`, `normal`, `large` and `xlarge`. Check this link for more information - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html